# How to write predicate to filter array of dictionaries?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, dictionary

I have array of dictionaries, dictionary contains key as NSString and value as integer. I have tried the following code but not getting result.

```
NSPredicate *objPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ = %@", key, [NSNumber numberWithInt:value]];

NSArray  *filteredArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:objPredicate];
```

Comment: Your dictionary cann't have a integer, only objects could be stored in dictionary, arrays, set... You must have a NSNumber inside your dictionary: this probable work fine: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ = %@", key, value];

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
NSPredicate *objPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self[%@] = %@", key, @(value)];

NSArray  *filteredArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:objPredicate];
```